# Keep Program From Error State When Network Connection is Lost

Tags: c#

I went to the code review community to look over a snippet I produced. They seemed particularly interested in the method I use to keep the program running if there is a network connection issue with the database. I have posted the link to my question below.

[Link to Code Review Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149197/bandwidth-reporter/149211?noredirect=1#comment280565_149211)

My question to you guys is, what is the best practice for keeping a program running while connection to the database is lost?

**Code in Question**

```
private void ReestablishDatabaseConnection()
        {
            bool broken = true;
            conn.ConnectionString = r.getSQLConnString();

            while (broken)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    conn.Close();
                    broken = false;
                }
                catch (Exception){}
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question to you guys is, what is the best practice for keeping a
>   program running while connection to the database is lost?

It depends on the type of application.

From the current code, if the machine is not able to connect to Database, and if you call this method for once, then it'll keep on running inside the loop!

So, it is only wasting the CPU cycles and doing nothing productive.

I'd suggest you to throw away this code, don't care much about connectivity issue in the code. Handle them with proper exception-logging. And, you may try re-connecting for 2-3 times OR more depending on the severity of the application.

If there is some network error OR any error/exception, do proper logging and take proper care that the issue is handled properly without any production loss.

About the suggestive part, don't let your code not run OR break just because of an exception.

Design your application in such a way that from the user's perspective, he/she doesn't get frustrated with the functionality and you too should have command over the application.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, you are helpful.

Comment: @DavidRichards - Thanks for the compliment, :)